# How to save web page to file - with a print style

Tags: css

I need to save web page, which would be in a print style (like when I use File->Print...). I could use Firefox or Chrome for this.

Comment: what is the quetion? you can use [file > print] in both chrome and firefox...

Comment: You could print to pdf then save that but I don't think you can save a webpage with it's print styles

Comment: I don't need to make hard copy or gewnerate pdf. I need to save a webpage to my hdd (.html), but I want it with "print style" (without buttons, frames etc.)

Comment: Best you can do is save the webpage and then edit the css so it uses the print styles then

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Media Query for the 'Print' class.

```
@media print {
   …
}
```

Then you can manually omit elements you do not want displayed when your page is printed.

That, or import a separate stylesheet, exclusively for printers.

```
@import "print.css" print;
```